# Comparar una lista de caracteres con un entero

Tags: lista, haskell, caracteres

En un curso de matemáticas, en el examen correspondiente al semestre de Haskell, se planteó la siguiente consigna:

Dada una lista de caracteres y un natural n, implementar una función que devuelva el carácter que ocupa la posición n en la lista. Considere que n es menor o igual que el largo de la lista (no hay que controlarlo).

Por ejemplo `elemento ['d','f','j']` `2` = `'f'`

Respondo con el siguiente

```
elemento:: [Char] -> Int -> Char
elemento [] n = 0
elemento (a:css) n | (a:css) == n = a
                   | (a:css) /= n = elemento css (n-1)
```

pero anda mal ¿cómo comparo una lista de caracteres con un entero, si estos son de distinto tipo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los enteros son para determinar la posición, no los tienes que comparar con los elementos de la lista.

En el enunciado te dice que el argumento `n` es menor o igual a la longitud de la cadena, así que es simple hacer una función recursiva que vaya recorriendo la cadena hasta llegar al caracter que buscas. Si `n==1`, devuelve el primer elemento; en caso contrario, se repite la búsqueda con el resto de la lista:

```hs
elemento:: [Char] -> Int -> Char
elemento (a:xs) 1 = a
elemento (a:xs) n = elemento xs (n-1)
```

Aunque así funciona y cumple con el enunciado, se podrían incluir las casuísticas que producen error. Para ello cambiamos la función para que devuelva un `Maybe Char`, que es lo más habitual en haskell:

```hs
elemento:: [Char] -> Int -> Maybe Char
elemento (a:xs) 1 = Just a
elemento (a:xs) n | n > 1 = elemento xs (n-1)
                  | otherwise = Nothing
elemento _ _ = Nothing
```